# trying to reverse complicated function in R

Tags: r, function

```
myfnS <- function(S,T,pH,D,f,r,I0) {

f1 <- 0.78*sqrt(S/35)*exp(T/26)

f2 <- 42*exp(T/17)

alpha <- 0.106*((f1*f^2)/(f1^2 + f^2))*exp((pH - 8)/0.56) + 0.52*(1 + T/43)*(S/35)*((f2*f^2)/(f2^2 + f^2))*exp(-D/6) + 0.00049*f^2*exp(-(T/27 + D/16))

TLsph <- (20*log(r*1000, base = 10))

I <- I0 - TLsph - ((alpha)*r)

return(I)
}
```

I'm trying to plug in I, to get a value for r but I'm not sure how to do that.

values for other things remain fixed; 
`for example for (I=50, S=34, T=10.5, pH-8.1, D=0.0395, f=10.3, I0=192)` - how do i find the `value of r`?

Comment: Your function gives me an error, do you mean `alpha <- 0.106*((f1*f^2)/(f1^2 + f^2))*exp((pH - 8)/0.56) + 0.52(1 + T/43)(S/35)((f2*f^2)/(f2^2 + f^2))*exp(-D/6) + 0.00049*f^2*exp(-(T/27 + D/16))` I added multiply operator before the first `exp`

Answer (score 0):

In R there's no way that I know of to run a function in reverse. However, you could use something similar to [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to zero in on a value of `r` that gives you an `I` of 50.

First though, the function needs to be cleaned up. Using `T` as an argument is a problem since that's also short for `TRUE`, so I changed it to `tt`. I also added in `*` operators where implied before.

```
myfnS <- function(S,tt,pH,D,f,r,I0) {

f1 <- 0.78*sqrt(S/35)*exp(tt/26)

f2 <- 42*exp(tt/17)

alpha <- 0.106*((f1*f^2)/(f1^2 + f^2))*exp((pH - 8)/0.56) + 
    0.52*(1 + (tt)/43)*(S/35)*((f2*f^2)/(f2^2 + f^2))*exp(-D/6) + 
    0.00049*f^2*exp(-(tt/27 + D/16))

TLsph <- (20*log(r*1000, base = 10))

I <- I0 - TLsph - ((alpha)*r)

return(I) }
```

Then a way to iterate through values of r to get closer to an I of 50. As r goes up, I goes down. Once a value for r is found that gets within 1 of 50, r is returned. This threshold can be adjusted to get a more precise guess.

```
iterateR <- function(I=50, r=1){
    if (abs(I - myfnS(r, S=34, tt=10.5, pH=8.1, D=0.0395, f=10.3, I0=192)) < 1) {
        return(r)
    }
    else if(I - myfnS(r, S=34, tt=10.5, pH=8.1, D=0.0395, f=10.3, I0=192) > 1) {
        iterateR(r=r-1)
    }
    else if(I - myfnS(r, S=34, tt=10.5, pH=8.1, D=0.0395, f=10.3, I0=192) < 1) {
        iterateR(r=r+1)
    }
}
iterateR(I=50, r=1)
#> 47
myfnS(r=47, S=34, tt=10.5, pH=8.1, D=0.0395, f=10.3, I0=192)
#> 50.8514607488626
```

An r of 47 gives an I of 50.85

Comment: R has lots of related functions built in. `stats::uniroot` for instance implements the Newton–Raphson method; you could thus e.g. run `uniroot(function (r) myfnS(r, S=34, tt=10.5, pH=8.1, D=0.0395, f=10.3, I0=192) - 50, c(0, 100))`, which yields 47.71046.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know about that.